# Label text size in a Radar Chart using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I re-ask my question. MPAndroidChart is great but it is almost a showstopper not to be able to resize the labels.
I've looked in the doc but I can't find anything.
I just found a data.setValueTextSize.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by getting the objects of X and Y axis of the radar chart and calling the setTextSize method on them:

XAxis:

```
XAxis xAxis = radarChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setTextSize(24f);
```

YAxis:

```
YAxis yAxis = radarChart.getYAxis();
yAxis.setTextSize(15f);
```

example output:

[image: radarChartVariousTextSizes]

official documentary:

```
/**
 * sets the size of the label text in pixels min = 6f, max = 24f, default
 * 10f
 *
 * @param size
 */

public void setTextSize(float size) {...}
```

Comment: It works great with the radar chart. How does it work with a pie chart?